# C# to calculate HTML document size by Url

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, visual-studio, size

I want to get HTML height and width for given url. I am using visual studio 2008 and this is for asp.net application.

I have no idea how to do it. I am looking for some method calculate and return width and height of the browser window that would fit the WHOLE content.

please help!

Thanks

Comment: size of url?? do u mean length?

Comment: I think the height and width is based on the size of the browser window. Please define what you mean by height and width?

Comment: What exactly is an APS.net application?

Comment: yes size of the browser window. How to do this ?

Comment: @Ramhound  I think he means ASP.net

Comment: Err - you can't. End of story.

Comment: Why do you want this? Maybe if you told more of the story someone could advise on a different approach...

Comment: @leo87 do you want to change the size of a pop up window?

Comment: Do you want to determine how large (height and width) another page (aka URL in your question) is without navigating to it?  You could use an object or iframe and use the DOM to get that information when you embed that page in the object.  There's no way to get it without rendering the page, especially if it's dynamic.

Comment: it's like this. my resolution is 1024*768. when I open a some websites I am getting scroll bars in my browser. So I just trying to find it programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to do what you think you want to do.

I think your real question is "how do I make my webpage fit properly in the browser?"  The answer is to scale and adjust your page on the client-side with Javascript and CSS rather than to change things on the server-side.  A well written webpage will resize itself if the user resizes the browser.  It shouldn't have to do a postback to the server to adjust its size.

Comment: No such thing as a stupid question :)  As long as you've learnt something then it's all good.

Answer (score 1):

Basically it's not possible serverside. You can use [JavaScript](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/browserw.htm) to calculate it clientside, but the best/recommended approach is to learn how to use HTML and CSS correctly, and design a fluent layout, that automatically scales.

Answer (score 1):

There has to be an actual call to the page so that you can find the size of the screen of the browser making the call. To find that you can use the [HttpCapabilitiesBase.ScreenPixelsHeight Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpcapabilitiesbase.screenpixelsheight.aspx)